# Front end only version of Init hook?

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm trying to build a feature into my theme that relies on doing things before the headers are sent. So naturally I hooked into the Init hook like so:

```
add_action('init', 'my_function');
```

But the problem is that I only want my_function to run if the user is not looking at the admin section or the login page.

So what hook can I use that is front-end only but is run before the headers are sent. [Looking at the API reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), there doesn't appear to be any, and obviously conditionals don't work that early in the runtime.

So other than searching the URL for /wp-admin/ and /wp-login/ (which seems clunky to me) I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap up your action's hooks and function in an `if(!is_admin()){}`

Like so :

```
if(!is_admin()) {
  //Style
  add_action('init', 'style');

  function style()
  {
      wp_enqueue_style('style', THEMEROOT . '/css/your.css');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it. Using the `wp` action hook is late enough to provide access to the query and therefore the conditionals, but still happens before the template is set up.

```
<?php
function my_function() {
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! is_login_page() ) {
        // Enqueue scripts, do theme magic, etc.
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'my_function' );

function is_login_page() {
    return in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php'));
}
```

**Edit:** I misunderstood what you meant by headers (I was thinking about `wp_head`... too much theme coding lately!). I'm now assuming you're trying to beat the `send_headers` action:

```
function my_function() {
    if ( 'index.php' == $GLOBALS['pagenow'] ) {
        // Pre-header processing on the front-end
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_function' );
```

It's not super-elegant, but at least it's concise. And [it seems likely it will continue to work](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11871#comment:5), which is always good news.

Comment: WP is called after headers are sent, so it won't work for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

here is some fine and cool solution, hope you all will like it.

```
function my_func(){
 if ( !is_admin())
 {

 // add code here for show only in front-end or create another function outside this block and call that function here.
 }
 else
 {
 // add code here for show only in admin or create another function outside this block and call that function here.
}}add_action ('init', 'my_func');
```

that is all , use and see the magic.

Comment: `is_admin() ` returns true for Ajax requests as well. For example, if you're doing infinite scroll on the frontend then `is_admin()` will return true.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for only front-end (not admin) is also to check the referer, because there are some ajax calls which direct to non `/wp-admin` url sequence, and `is_admin()` is not fixed. It seems he is looking right at this piece of URL.

```
// Skip for admin
if ( is_admin() || ( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] && strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'wp-admin' ) !== false ) ) {
    return;
}
```